# GA4 new users higher than total users

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have been generating GA reports monthly for reporting and I realised that after porting over from UA tag to GA4 tag, the number of new users has been consistently above the number of total users.

I do have an assumption for this and would like some feedback. As my company handles the data tags in-house, we got our IT team to replace the UA tags with the GA4 tags manually on our website. By doing this, we actually saw that no data was received for a few days while the GA4 tags started to stream data in. Subsequently, once data came in, new users increased. Could this be due to us manually replacing the UA tags with GA4 tags, thus inflating the number of new users above total users?

Do let me know if this could be possible.

Comment: I would think the new users would never exceed the total users number. It is hard to say for sure without more information on your setup. Are you comparing the Total Users vs. New Users in the GA4 property only? If you are trying to compare across Universal and GA4 they won't match because of how they vary in their calculations of the metric: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11986666?hl=en#users&zippy=%2Cin-this-article.